# Access a child state from a child state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I want to access a child state from a child state but I get : `angular.js:14195 Error: Could not resolve '#/projects/detailProject' from state 'projects.list`

**these are the states :**

```
function routeConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('projects', {
            url: '/projects',
            template : '<ui-view  autoscroll="true" autoscroll-body-top></ui-view>',
            abstract: true,
            title: 'Les projets',
            controller : 'ProjectController',
            sidebarMeta: {
                icon: 'ion-compose',
                order: 250,
            },
        })
        .state('projects.add', {
            url: '/add',
            templateUrl: 'app/pages/projects/add/projects.html',
            title: 'Ajouter un projet',
            sidebarMeta: {
                order: 800,
            },
        })
        .state('projects.list', {
            url: '/list',
            params : { projectId : null},
            templateUrl: 'app/pages/projects/list/listProjects.html',
            title: 'List',
            sidebarMeta: {
                order: 900,
            },
        })
         .state('projects.detail', {
             url: '/detail',
             templateUrl: 'app/pages/projects/detail/detailProject.html',
             title: 'Detail du projet',
        });
    $urlRouterProvider.when('/projects','/projects/list');
}
```

And I'm trying to access the child state trough :

```
<button type="button" id="Edit" name="Edit" ng-click="goToPath('#/projects/detailProject', p.id)"class="btn btn-primary btn-raised">Editer</button></div>
```

`And this is my **goToPath** method :

```
$scope.goToPath = function ( path, pid ) {
    $scope.pid = pid;
    $state.go(path, {projectId : pid} );
};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With UI-Router you define states and navigate to those states. So your `$state.go` should get a state and not a path.

```
<button ng-click="goToPath('projects.detail', p.id)">Editer</button>
```